# Make Applescript Editor record keys that were press

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm fairly new to applescript (I know a thing or two about it) but I not able to do advance things with it. Ok, the question is I need a script that will record/monitor keys I press. But not by typing it directly into a input box like this script:

```
display dialog "" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
set answer to text returned of the result
display dialog answer buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

For example if I type, "www.google.com" into a browser and then go back to applescript, it will have recorded, "www.google.com" Thanks for any help creating this script.

Comment: AppleScript cannot do that

Comment: @vadian Ok, but are you sure there is absolutely no way to do what I mention above. Or is there anything that could perhaps come close to it?

Comment: Not with vanilla AppleScript because AS runs basically on a single thread. To monitor keyboard events you need at least a second thread to avoid blocking the UI. Maybe AppleScriptObjC or AS combined with Cocoa could do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the URL thats been typed into the browser (using Safari) you simply do:

```
tell application "Safari" to get URL of first document
```

But, I believe that you want to get what's inside a specific input field on the web page, right? Then you can do like this:
1) Write "qwerty" into the input field that your'e interested to read from.
2) Run this script on AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell first document
        set numberOfInputFields to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\").length;"
        repeat with i from 0 to numberOfInputFields - 1
            set inputValueScript to "document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\")[" & i & "].value"
            set inputValue to (do JavaScript inputValueScript)
            if inputValue is equal to "qwerty" then
                display alert "Index of input field: " & i
                return
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Then you'll get the index of the input field. Put that number into this script and hit run:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell first document
        set indexOfInputField to "place-the-number-here"
        set inputValueScript to "document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\")[" & indexOfInputField & "].value"
        set inputValue to (do JavaScript inputValueScript)
    end tell
    display alert "Text in input field " & indexOfInputField & ": " & inputValue
end tell
```

And you'll get what's been typed into that field ("qwerty" if you haven't changed it from last script). As you see, these scripts are using JavaScript to read from the web page. If my answer isn't exactly what you want, you can experiment with other JavaScript commands, found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) for example.

Comment: Thanks, you guys are awesome. Wish I could understand half of what all this coding/scripting means. :) But I hope I'll get there some day...